# Storing NSCombobox history across run

Tags: macos, appkit

I'm writing a little Mac OS utility app that has a NSComboBox for URLs.

I'd like the history to be persistent but I'm not sure where/when/how to save the data.

If this was an iPhone app I would just persist the array of URLs when the app is told it's going to exit but I'm not sure that's the best way on Mac OS.

Should I just do the same thing and enocde the array into a file when the app quits ?
Or should I be using the CFPreferences ?
Or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferences seem a fitting place for me. Instead of *CFPreferences*, I'd use the Cocoa native [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that you can connect the combobox in the interface editor to the NSUserDefaults controller to automate storing those values. I can't check because I'm not at a Mac at the moment.